# Rails 3 Select Distinct Order By Number of Occurrences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my models I have a country column. How would I go about selecting the top 3 countries based on how many models have that country?

Comment: if you share your model it's easier to figure out what you need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any further information you can try this out:

```
YourModel.group('country').order('count_country DESC').limit(3).count('country')
```

when you call count on a field rails automatically adds an `AS count_field_name` field to your query.

Count must be called at the end of the query because it returns an ordered hash.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how Rails adds a `count_*` field for the column in `.count()` -- did not know that!